# Order of execution in ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a question:

I have 4 functions that I wrote in the componentDidMount(), but I notice that the order in which I write these functions is not respected.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.checkPermission(); (1)
    this.checkInitialBluetoothState(); (2)
    this.disconnect() (3)
    this.scans() (4)
  }
```

I receive the console log in order from; (3) (2) (1) and (4) and sometimes  the (4) function is not performed and the app enters in a loop

Do you recommend linking one function to another by calling it?

Thank you

EDIT:

```
async checkPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Accesso Localizzazione',
          message: 'Richiesto accesso localizzazione',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'Ok',
        },
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("Accesso Localizzazione Permesso.")
      }
      else {
        console.log("Accesso Localizzazione Negato.")
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }
  }


  async checkInitialBluetoothState() {
    const isEnabled = await BluetoothStatus.state();
    console.log("Controllo bluetooth on o off", isEnabled);
    if (isEnabled == true) {
      console.log("Bluetooth attivo.")
    }
    else {
      Alert.alert(
        'Attenzione:',
        'Bluetooth non è attivo.'
      );
      Actions.homepageutente();
    }
  }


  disconnectDevice() {
    if (this.state.device1) {
      this.manager.cancelDeviceConnection(this.state.device1.id)
    }
    else {
      console.log("Device1 non connesso")
    }
    if (this.state.device2) {
      this.manager.cancelDeviceConnection(this.state.device2)
    }
    else {
      console.log("Device2 non connesso")
    }
  }


  scans() {
//....
```

Comment: console.log is not guaranteed to be synchronous

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko Do you refer to the console log inside the functions? Because I refer to it

Comment: Can you show us how you're logging them?

Comment: What do those functions do exactly?

Comment: @ApplePearPerson the logged is refered for example that inside any function I have a console.log, I refer to this when I follow the order of execution of the functions

Comment: @PeterCatalin The first one checks the permission to use the location, the second one checks if the bluetooth is one, the third checks if there is some devices connected. the Fourth starts a scan of devices

Comment: @Jack23 are those function synchronous? They have to be synchronous for the console.log to happen in the order you expect them to.

Comment: @PeterCatalin you are right! Well so Do you know why sometimes the fourth function is not called? Do you think that is better call it in the last function?

Comment: Can you show us the actual code for the functions?

Comment: I have edit my post :) Thank you all

Comment: You need to put `await` in front of the async functions if you want to wait for them to be resolved before moving onto the next function in that block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need async functions to execute in order. Do something like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.checkPermission(); (1)
    await this.checkInitialBluetoothState(); (2)
    this.disconnect() (3)
    this.scans() (4)
  }
```

Otherwise, the `async` functions will return immediately.